# Joda DateTime equals vs isEqual

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I've got two similar dates and I am doubtful about the comparison Joda DateTime api provides:

```
log.info("comparing:"+abrDateTime+": and :"+breakStart+":"+abrDateTime.equals(breakStart));
```

this prints

```
comparing:2015-07-14T12:25:47.000+05:30: and :2015-07-14T12:25:47.000+05:30:false
```

While with DateTime.isEqual

```
log.info("comparing:"+abrDateTime+": and :"+breakStart+":"+abrDateTime.isEqual(breakStart));
```

prints:

```
comparing:2015-07-14T12:25:47.000+05:30: and :2015-07-14T12:25:47.000+05:30:true
```

Problem is I'm using DateTime.equals method everywhere in my app, should I change it to `isEqual`?

**NOTE:** Both instances got same same millis and same timezone as you can see in prints.

Comment: @RealSkeptic No, I dont think I am printing same. Please correct question if you can see any typo.

Comment: Can you provide reproducible code that creates those DateTime objects?

Comment: The log message should say "Comparing" + `abrDateTime` + " and " + `breakStart`, that's the typo.

Comment: Yep. Got it and changed it. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 13):

First, you may need to check your code, because the snippets that you give is printing the same object (which is `abrDateTime`), yet, in the `equals` and `isEqual` method, you compare the `abrDateTime` with `breakStart` object.

Second, at time like this, the best way is to check the API documentation.
for [equals](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), the doc state that :

> Compares this object with the specified object for equality based on the millisecond instant, chronology and time zone

and the [isEqual](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#isEqual(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)), the doc state that :

> Is this instant equal to the instant passed in comparing solely by millisecond

So, the choice is , do you want to check the time only based on its time? then go with `isEqual` method. Or, if you want to check also the timezone and chronology, then go with `equals`

---

**EDIT:**

Addressing your comment,

1. Chronology and why it's needed to compare
   => Taken from the [doc](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/org/joda/time/Chronology.java#Chronology)

   > Chronology provides access to the individual date time fields for a chronological calendar system.

   Therefore, you can think that `Chronology` as a class which contain the date and time fields for a specific calendar system. (such as, ISO, Gregorian, Buddhist, etc.)

   It is needed, because you don't want to compare two date but in different calendar system. example, let say, in islamic calendar system, first of June in gregorian would be [14 SHa`baan](http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php?mode=ger-hij&day=1&month=6&year=2015&date_result=1) (this is my opinion so it might be different from what the API author intended as the reason is not documented)
2. If you only want to compare the mills and time zone. Then I guess you could just use `isEqual` method.

Comment: Thanks @kucing, It's just I dont understand what the heck chronology  means and why it's needed to compare. Comparing millis and timezone should have done the job.

Comment: @sachin. Think of it likes calendar system. Such as julian, iso, etc. You can check it in here http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_chronology.html

Answer (score 3):

The `equals` method of `ReadableInstant` (superclass of `DateTime`) also incorporates the `Chronology`, while `isEqual` strictly looks at the instant in time (milliseconds since epoch). In your case, the two objects have different `Chronology`s.

From the [Javadocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Compares this object with the specified object for equality based on the millisecond instant and the Chronology. All ReadableInstant instances are accepted.
>
> To compare two instants for absolute time (ie. UTC milliseconds ignoring the chronology), use isEqual(ReadableInstant)or Comparable.compareTo(Object).